# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'summary'

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, google-colaboratory

while trying to view the model of sequential neural network, it shows an error,"list object has no attribute 'summary'.

i tried

```
from keras.models import load_model

enter code '''model= (['''
   ''' Dense(16,input_shape=(1,),activation='relu'),'''
    '''Dense(32,activation='relu'),'''
   ''' Dense(2,activation='softmax')'''
'''])'''
'''model.summary'''
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'summary'

Answer (score 0):

add the keyword **Sequential**

example:

```
model = Sequential([ 
        Dense(16, input_shape = (1,), activation = "relu"),
        Dense(32, activation = "relu"),
        Dense(2, activation = "softmax") 
])
```